# JDOM - cloning MULTIPLE elements - The method clone() is undefined for the type List

Tags: java, jdom

I recently asked question and one member helped me a lot  how to clone some element and to remove elements from only one element. But same methods are not able to use when there are multiple elements in input XML (this is not duplicate question). On example if I have input XML in this format(of course number of elements is always different):

```
<SyncMXAUTHCI>
  <MXAUTHCISet>
    <CI>
      <CINAME>COMPUTER68</CINAME>
    </CI>
  </MXAUTHCISet>
</SyncMXAUTHCI>
```

and whant to have its clone

```
<SyncMXAUTHCI>
  <MXAUTHCISet>
    <CI>
      <CINAME>COMPUTER68</CINAME>
    </CI>
    <CI>
      <CINAME>COMPUTER68</CINAME>
    </CI>
  </MXAUTHCISet>
</SyncMXAUTHCI>
```

I will use this and it works perfectly:

```
Document erJdom = erData.getData();
Element root = erJdom.getRootElement();
Namespace erJdomNamespace = root.getNamespace();

Element incSet = root.getChild("MXAUTHCISet", erJdomNamespace);
incSet.addContent((Element)incSet.getChild("CI", erJdomNamespace).clone());
```

But what If I have 2 CI elements in input XML:

```
<SyncMXAUTHCI>
  <MXAUTHCISet>
    <CI>
      <CINAME>COMPUTER68</CINAME>
    </CI>
    <CI>
      <CINAME>COMPUTER100</CINAME>
    </CI>
  </MXAUTHCISet>
</SyncMXAUTHCI>
```

I tried this with `getChildren` but it won't compile because:

```
incSet.addContent((Element)incSet.getChildren("CI", erJdomNamespace).clone());
```

Then it says The method clone() is undefined for the type List

How to clone multiple elements? THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot clone multiple elements in one operation. You have to loop through each Element, and clone each one individually.... (and you should be using JDOM 2.0.5 !)

```
List<Element> toadd = new ArrayList<Element>();
foreach (Element e : incSet.getChildren("CI", erJdomNamespace)) {
  toadd.addContent(e.clone());
}
incSet.addContent(toadd);
```

I have edited the code to use two seperate arrays to avoid a concurrent modification exception.

Comment: Thank you again for your effort and time. I imported in eclipse some jdom.jar from my system (it is some IBM Tivoli Maximo application). Are you telling me this will not work with my JDOM.JAR? should I download some jdom.jar file which contains 2.0.5 classes? I am having error with your code: Element cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: how to use JDOM 2.0.5?if that is the solution?

Comment: I downloaded jdom2-2.0.5.jar file but now my whole class has errors. In eclipse I added it in ADD EXTERNAL JAR. I added import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.Namespace; because those are the paths but it won't compile. Also error is still on " foreach (Element e : incidentSet.getChildren("CI", erJdomNamespace)) "

Comment: I am trying something like this: but I am affraid of that concurrent modification exception: Is this good approach?:    List<Element> invList = (List<Element>)incidentSet.getChildren("CI",erJdomNamespace);
    
    
    for(Element e: invList)
    {
     
     Element inv = (Element)e.clone();
     incidentSet.addContent(inv);
     
    }